# SQL multiple ORDER BY columns sort by Desc and Asc

Tags: mysql, sql

This is what I've tried so far:

```
 SELECT M.ID, M.NAME, M.SEQ
 FROM M JOIN MCA
 ON M.ID = MCA.M_ID 
 JOIN MC
 ON MCA.CAT_ID = MC._ID
 WHERE MCA.CAT_ID = "
            + inputCategoryID
            + " AND (M.NAME LIKE '"
            + inputSearch.replace("'", "''")
            + "%' OR M.NAME LIKE '%"
            + inputSearch.replace("'", "''")
            + "%' ) AND M.START_DATE <= CURRENT_DATE " +
AND M.EXPIRY_DATE >= CURRENT_DATE " +
ORDER BY M.SEQ DESC, M.NAME ASC
```

**SAMPLE RESULTS:**

```
ID     NAME     SEQ
1      Tes1     0
2      Arj2     0
3      Jfa3     1
4      Pof4     0
```

**DESIRED RESULTS:**

```
 ID     NAME     SEQ
 3      Jfa3     1
 2      Arj2     0
 4      Pof4     0
 1      Tes1     0
```

But if the same SEQ value (i.e., 0, 0), it should display Name alphabetically. Any ideas how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: That is what your `order by` statement should do.  Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: I will update my post

Comment: I don't think the query you have is the query that's actually executing. The results you get do not match what should happen.